# Declaring 2 variables in a for() loop

Tags: java

I have 2 loops like this

goodexpressions and badexpressions are string arrays

```
for(int i =0; i < goodexpressions.length; i++) {}
```

&

```
for(int j =0; j < badexpressions.length; j++) {}
```

i'm trying to declare both of these in one loop, i've got this so far but it's not correct

```
for(int b = 0 , c = 0; b < goodexpressions.length; b++ c < badexpressions.length; c++)
```

what am I supposed to do to correct this statement?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It makes the code hard to read, which is never a good thing.

Comment: To count the number of strings in the arrays.

Comment: Are they both `String[]` ?

Comment: Then count the number of strings in the first array, do the same for the second one, and add the results. To avoid code duplication, put the looping and counting code is a separate method, and call this method twice: `int sum = countStringsIn(badexpressions) + countStringsIn(goodexpressions);`

Comment: Edited to add that info, yes they are.

Comment: Why not just use `goodexpressions.length` + `badexpressions.length` then?

Comment: I mis-told what I'm trying to do. I don't want to add them up, I need both of them separately so I can check if anothers tring contains any of the arrays combined. IDEA= combine the arrays and check its length.  will do that now.

Comment: So you want to find the length of both arrays combined, but make sure that there are no duplicates? Just do `Arrays.asList(goodexpressions)` and `Arrays.asList(badexpressions)`, then create a new `HashSet` and use the `addAll` method to add both `Arrays.asList(goodexpressions)` and `Arrays.asList(badexpressions)`. Finally, just call `.size()` on the HashList. (`.asList()` returns an array converted to a `List`, which you need to use the `addAll` method on a `HashSet`. A `HashSet` does not allow duplicate entries.) Your intentions are unclear, so I may not have answered your question well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although what you are trying to do seems like a bad idea, here is a piece of code that will work. I don't know if it does exactly what you want it to though, since that isn't completely clear to me.

```
for(int b = 0, c = 0; b < goodexpressions.length || c < badexpressions.length; b++, c++) { }
```

When doing this, though, you still have to check if `b` and `c` are inside the array index range. You can also replace the `||` with `&&` in which case you won't have to do that anymore, but you will be missing some items if the arrays are not equally long.

Comment: instead I just combined goodexpressions and badexpressions by myself(new string[] and copy pasted the strings in the 2 mentioned ararys) and used that one array instead. i wanted to use the apache library's array combiner but that would import unnecessary data and i am coding on android, and still, mobile phones have limited resources. thank you for the nice answer.

Comment: @joedacoolguy "import unnecessary data" - huh? "mobile phones have limited resources" - not THAT limited. I wouldn't load Spring on one but utility libraries never killed anyone. Odds are your graphical assets will take up more space.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you should do one of the following. Say you have two lists `A` and `B`...

If you want to loop over all the elements in both lists `A` and `B`, create a new list, or array, holding the elements of both lists and loop over that list.

```
for (int i = 0; i < combinedAandB.length; i++) {
    ...
}
```

If you want to loop over all the *combinations* of elements from list `A` and list `B`, you have to use nested loops.

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < B.length; k++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

*Update:* Concerning the two-variable for-loop approach in your question and the other two answers: Note that since both those variables will take on *exactly the same values* in each iteration of the loop, you can just as well use just one variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < goodexpressions.length || i < badexpressions.length; i++) { }
```

But also note that this will not do you any good in terms of avoiding code duplication, since you still have to everything to both, `goodexpressions[i]` and `badexpressions[i]`. A better approach might be to write a method holding the loop and calling that method once with `goodexpressions` and once with `badexpressions`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you are asking:

```
for (int b = 0, c = 0; 
     b < goodexpressions.length && c < badexpressions.length; 
     b++, c++)
```

Note that there are exactly 2 semicolons separators on an old-style `for` loop.

And based on your comment, I think this might be better:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(goodexpressions.length, badexpressions.length); i++)
```

---

Notes:

1. It is not at all clear what the loop body is going to do.  That will determine the right way to combine the loops ... or if it is just a bad idea to combine them at all.
2. The above code is designed to stop at the smaller of the two lengths.  If you want to stop at the larger, change `&&` to `||` and `min` to `max`.  However, if you do that, you also need to take care to avoid array bounds exceptions.
3. Unless the intent is to use both `goodexpression[i]` and `badexpression[i]` at the same time (e.g. compare them, combine them, and so on), your code will be more readable and more efficient if you use two separate loops.
4. Another possibility might be to simply check that the two arrays have the same length.

Comment: You are right about the first.  For the second, it is unclear what the OP wants.  My assumption was that he wanted to stop at that point.  But if not, my code can trivially be adapted.

Comment: I removed the downvote, but anyone reading this answer should keep in mind that some elements will not be tested if the arrays are not of the same length.

Comment: And obviously changing `&&` to `||` and `min` to `max` can cause index out of bounds exceptions on the smaller array. The bottom line is, "combining" two arrays in this fashion is not a good idea.